# Javascript - Cannot initialize a AWS Textract object with AWS-SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, amazon-textract

I want to use the textract API for document analysis, but when I tried to create an instance of `AWS.Textract` it throws an error saying

`module initialization error: TypeError`

I tried different things, 
Initially I tries this,

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const Textract = new AWS.Textract();
```

it didn't work and said cannot find object

then after some googling, I found this [link](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/2657) and adjusted the code to this

```
require('aws-sdk/clients/textract');
var textractClient = new AWS.Textract();
```

and this,

```
const Textract = require('aws-sdk/clients/textract');
var textractClient = new Textract();
```

None of these are working, what am doing wrong here?

Comment: what version of node and what version of the sdk are you using?

Comment: node: 8.10

"aws-sdk": "^2.475.0",

Answer (score 4):

Don't take offence but your title is bit confusing because it refers to aws-cli however the code snippet in your description is in nodejs. Can you kindly clarify which is which?

In JavaScript/nodejs SDK you can initialize Amazon Textract object as illustrated by the following code snippet :

> ```or-tag-here
> 'use strict';
>
> // Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
> var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
>
> // Set region
> AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
>
> var textract = new AWS.Textract();
>
> // Set parameters for the API
> var params = {
>     DocumentLocation: { /* required */
>       S3Object: {
>         Bucket: 'syumaK-bucket',
>         Name: 'document.pdf'
>       }
>     },
>     FeatureTypes: [ /* required */
>       'TABLES','FORMS'
>     ],
>     NotificationChannel: {
>       RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::19250632xxxx:role/AWSTextractRole', /* required */
>       SNSTopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:19250632xxxx:AmazonTextractTopic1562662993926'/* required */
>     }
>   };
>   textract.startDocumentAnalysis(params, function(err, data) {
>     if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
>     else     console.log(data);           // successful response
>   });
> ```

I have tested the above code snippet using the following environment spec:

- OS : Mac High Sierra v10.13.6
- aws-sdk: "^2.489.0"

Comment: the answer is I need to put a region, you were right